# Return object in array with highest value of method

Tags: c#, methods, foreach, return

I have an array of Pokemons.
Pokemons have an abstract method vitesse(vitesse = speed in french), which change depending of the type of pokemon.

I also have a class TabPokemon which generate my array of pokemons.
In this class I want to calculate the fastest pokemon.

This is my method :

```
public Pokemon plusRapide()
{
    Pokemon winner;
    double vitesse = 0.0;
    foreach(Pokemon p in tab)
    {
        if(p.vitesse()> vitesse)
        {
            vitesse = p.vitesse();
            winner = p;
        }

    }
    return winner;
}
```

It shows me an error on the return statement because it is assigned locally.
How can I return the object Pokemon with the greatest speed value?

Comment: Well, what would you want to return if `tab` is empty, or if the `vitesse` value is negative for all elements? If you'd want to return `null`, then just assign `winner` as null initially.

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, I'd encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions as early as possible.

Comment: This could by done using linq in a single line of code - `return tab.OrderBy(p => p.vitesse()).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Or without sorting by using MoreLINQ's `MaxBy`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess I really should download and investigate that MoreLINQ library... It's popping out everywhere lately :-)

Comment: You already answered this question @JonSkeet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the Pokemon object by `Pokemon winner = null;` on the first line of the method.